# JenkinsPipelineUnit helper can intercept text param call but not string param call

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-pipeline-unit

How can I get [JenkinsPipelineUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit) to intercept both text() and string() param calls?  I have code that triggers a build with a few params.  I want to write a nice unit test to check that it does what it should.  However, the string() calls are not intercepted so I cannot test them.  I can test the text() call.

**Yes*, it is possible to write unit tests for Jenkins pipeline code vs testing via jenkins production jobs.  This project + shared libraries makes jenkins into a much better tool.*

Any ideas on how I could do this?  I looked in the [JenkinsPipelineUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit) project but didn't find an example that fit and couldn't figure out where to look in the runtime objects.

I do see that the project's [BasePipelineTest.groovy](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/blob/a469daf904e8c8e9957dea6e2eea9c59150fd9e2/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/BasePipelineTest.groovy#L214) links string to its [stringInterceptor](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/blob/a469daf904e8c8e9957dea6e2eea9c59150fd9e2/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/BasePipelineTest.groovy#L26) which seems to just eat it the string.  Maybe, I can unregister theirs...

**Example**

```
def triggeringParams = [:]
....
for (def param in ['text', 'string']) {
    helper.registerAllowedMethod(param, [LinkedHashMap],
            { LinkedHashMap data ->
                triggeringParams << data
            }
    )
}


thisScript = helper.loadScript('''
    package resources
    return this''')

def params = []
params << thisScript.text(name: 'MULTILINE_PARAM', value: '\nline1\nline2')
params << thisScript.string(name: 'STRING_PARAM', value: 'a string')

thisScript.build(job: 'myJob', parameters: params)

println triggeringParams
```

**Results**

```
[
    [name:JOB_PROPERTIES, value:
        line1
        line2]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong type was the problem.  The project's [BasePipelineTest.groovy](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/blob/a469daf904e8c8e9957dea6e2eea9c59150fd9e2/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/BasePipelineTest.groovy#L214) links string to its [stringInterceptor](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/blob/a469daf904e8c8e9957dea6e2eea9c59150fd9e2/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/BasePipelineTest.groovy#L26) which seems to just eat it the string and uses register Map not LinkedHashMap.  So, the first is found before mine and boom, the string doesn't show in my collector.

If I modify my code to use the more generic map it works

```
void addParameterHelpers() {
    for (def param in ['text', 'string']) {
        helper.registerAllowedMethod(param, [Map],
                { LinkedHashMap data ->
                    triggeringParams << data
                }
        )
    }
}
```